# Getting "Undefined method" when trying to create filter in a controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, filter, ruby-on-rails-5, before-filter

I'm using Rails 5.  In my application controller, I have:

```
private

def current_user
 @current_user ||= User.find_by(id: session[:user_id])
end
```

then, in another controller I have:

```
class MyObjectsController < ApplicationController

before_filter !current_user { redirect_to root_path }, except: [:search]
```

but I'm getting the error:

```
undefined method `current_user' for MyObjectsController:Class
```

What am I doing wrong and how can I apply a filter to every method in my controller except the `search` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you're using it, the `current_user method` is being called when the class is loaded, it won't be available at that level.  It's only available during the request.  This is what you probably meant.

```
before_filter :require_current_user, except: [:search]

def require_current_user
  redirect_to(:root, :notice => "you must be logged in") unless current_user
end
```

If you're using devise, you should be able to

```
before_action :authenticate_user!, :except => [:search]
```